# how to authenticate if I run mongod with security.authorization: enabled?

Tags: mongodb

After initially installing mongodb and running mongod with `security.authorization: enabled` option, how do I authenticate myself?

I need to access Mongo Shell to create root account, but it requires authentication...

Comment: create user first then enable authorization

Answer (score 1):

According to [this guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) you should

1. first create an admin account
2. enable authorization and restart mongo instance

Answer (score 1):

When you run `mongod` with `authorization: enabled` it will ask for a password, *unless* you're connecting from the localhost, in which case you'll be able to connect and create users.

This is known as the [localhost exception](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/#localhost-exception), and it's the way they allow you to create a root or better off a **userAdmin** on the database. It won't ask you for a pwd.

You can of course, launch `mongod` without `autorization: enabled`, create the user, and re-launch. I find the previous approach far more practical than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run the mongo shell and it will run on localhost `port 27017` by default.

**Connection URL**: *mongodb://localhost:27017/your-project*

That will allow you to create root account without any password.

You can take help of [this article](https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-b9e8a924efac),
and also the official [MongoDB security options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security-options) configuration.